# Quel est le mot dont le développement s'est fait avec le plus de métonymies « successives » et est-ce significatif ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, lexique

La [métonymie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9tonymie) « utilise un mot pour signifier une idée distincte mais qui lui est associée » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tonymie)), et « est essentiellement un changement de désignation » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3197)) ; on dit qu'elle est « à l’origine du renouvellement de certains lexèmes » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tonymie#Enrichissement_du_vocabulaire), voir aussi à certains égards la [*catachrèse*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachr%C3%A8se#Lexicalisation)).

---

Quel serait le (un) mot employé aujourd'hui ayant connu le plus (un
relativement très) grand nombre de changements de signifié par
métonymies **successives** (sur l'emploi métonymique qui précède, indépendamment du [type](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tonymie#Types_de_relations_m%C3%A9tonymiques)) :

- Peut-on en retracer la séquence (signifiés, périodes) et brièvement
  discuter de ses raisons et circonstances particulières le cas échéant
  ?
- Ce genre de mot ou leur sens auraient-ils quelque chose de particulier et pourquoi la métonymie serait-elle productive à répétition ici alors que figée ailleurs ; s'agit-il simplement d'une question de perspective historique et d'utilité (à quel moment on observe le lexique et s'il y a à ce moment un besoin d'avoir un signe pour représenter de nouvelles réalités) ?

Comment: Un de mes professeurs aimait donner l'exemple de l'évolution du mot "bureau", qui désignait à l'origine un petit tapis étalé sur une table de travail, puis a désigné la table elle-même, puis la pièce où se trouve la table, puis le bâtiment, puis les personnes qui y travaillent, puis l'organisme qui emploie ces personnes, etc. A creuser...

Comment: J'avoue ne plus m'en rappeler... c'était il y a plus de 20 ans ! C'était en fait un professeur d'allemand, peut-être parlait-il du faux ami partiel *Büro* et de là, de l'origine du mot en français ?

Comment: Un peu hors sujet, mais intéressant: une métonymie ayant eu beaucoup de succès (un large développement horizontal, même si verticalement limitée à une seule étape de transformation), le contenu exprimé sous la forme [«contenant + ée»](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-%C3%A9e) (forme III.B1a/2 dans le lien) devenu dans la langue quotidienne presque exclusivement homonyme au contenant → *assietée, cuillerée, panerée, chaudierée* (habituelle quand j'étais jeune, mais non recensée dans les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés) se disent aujourd'hui principalement *assiette, cuiller, panier, chaudière.*

Answer (score 4):

Un de mes professeurs aimait donner l'exemple de l'évolution du mot "bureau", qui désignait à l'origine un petit tapis étalé sur une table de travail (sens aujourd'hui disparu), puis a désigné:

- la table elle-même
- la pièce où se trouve la table
- le bâtiment ou le lieu de travail
- les personnes qui y travaillent
- l'organisme qui emploie ces personnes

Comment: Il y avait quand j'étais plus jeune un historique de ce mot présenté à  la télévision sous forme de courte animation. On y donnait comme point de départ non le tapis, mais la toile servant à confectionner l'habit des moines, puis l'habit lui-même, et comme les moines constituaient alors l'essentiel des scriptes, on attribua le nom à la table. Une [autre source](http://www.leslyriades.fr/spip.php?article417) intéressante. Très bel exemple en effet!

Comment: On peut aussi ajouter le sens nouveau du mot dans le domaine informatique, où le *bureau* est l'espace de travail d'une interface graphique d'un système d'exploitation, où se trouvent les icônes.

Answer (score 1):

#### CALCUL

Par une première métonymie datant d’avant le français, le latin avait nommé ***calculus*** un caillou servant à compter, d’après l’acception plus large du mot qui signifiait simplement caillou.

Après un détour via ***calculare***, *« déterminer par le calcul »*, le français a déverbalisé le verbe calculer pour en faire ***calcul***, aujourd’hui homonye d’une autre transformation sémantique contemporaine du caillou latin, appliquée aux concrétions solides formées dans un organisme vivant et pouvant mener à diverses complications *(calculs rénaux*, par exemple).

Le calcul désigne aujourd’hui aussi bien, à divers niveaux d’inclusion et de généralité :

- une opération sur des valeurs
- le résultat de cette opération
- un ensemble de procédés permettant d’établir les opérations
- à un niveau plus familier, on désigne aussi simplement par *calcul* d’un côté l’arithmétique, d’un autre le calcul différentiel et intégral

Du calcul numérique qui permettrait de prédire l’issue de certains événements *(la mise sur orbite d’un satellite artificiel, par exemple)*, une métaphore (non une métonymie) nous mène au calcul qui est processus de détermination de certains évènements dont les règles mathématiques sont moins sûrement établies *(le devenir du cours d’un titre à la bourse, le résultat d’un match de tennis)* ou laissées de côté pour une autre méthode déductive *(prédiction du temps requis avant qu’un enfant se blesse dans un groupe peu surveillé)*.

Mais ce calcul qui envisage les effets de manière non-numérique a de nouveau, par métonymie, dérivé vers une nouvelle signification, celle du calcul qui organise les événements et tente de dévier le cours de ceux-ci à son avantage *(élaborer, déjouer un calcul)*.

De ce dernier, par métonymie encore, on désignera par calcul l’attitude ou le comportement d’une personne qui fait ce genre de calcul, terme que l’on pourra plus ou moins opposer à la spontanéité.

---

L’évolution décrite ici pour ce mot montre un mélange de nouvelles réalités, d’évolution dans l’analyse de comportements (sans pour autant que les comportements soient nouveaux) et de cette tendance naturelle au raccourcissement des termes communément utilisés.

Nouvelle réalité dans l’introduction des opérations mathématiques et de récupération d’un bien naturel et abondant permettant de les effectuer facilement, nouvelle méthode d’analyse numérique dans le cas du calcul différentiel et intégral, généralisation du sens existant dans le cas de procédés généraux d’établissement des règles logiques permettant d’effectuer des opérations.

Évolution dans l’analyse faite du processus d’estimation du résultat d’une séquence évènementielle, car il serait étrange d’envisager l’humain ne supputant pas du devenir en fonction du présent avant l’arrivée de l’arithmétique formalisée.

De façon similaire, il n’est pas vraisemblable que l’humanité ait attendu l’arrivée des mathématiques pour tenter activement de détourner à son avantage les situations, les gens et les biens. On supposera donc que le calcul s’est plutôt incarné comme une dénomination ingénieusement intuitive de ce genre de comportement, si correctement formulée qu’elle aurait porté un sérieux ombrage au terme qui en tenait lieu jusqu’alors.

Quant au raccourcissement, on le retrouvera dans les dénominations plus familières. Quel étudiant en sciences utilisera systématiquement calcul différentiel et intégral ? Lorsque la distinction est importante, il l’utilisera, certes, mais sinon, l’expression est beaucoup trop longue pour le confort.

---

#### MIDI

**Midi**, étymologiquement le milieu *(mi-)* du jour *(di)*, et ensuite :

- **Le nom de douze heures**, puis

  - **L’heure qui suit**, avant treize heures

    - Du précédent, en Belgique, **la pause de travail** qui survient alors.
  - Dans l’expression ***C’est midi (sonné)*** : en référence aux douze coups qui peuvent marquer une limite temporelle, diviser l’avant et l’après, et qui signifie alors qu’il n’y a plus moyen, que c’est impossible.
  - Dans l’expression ***marquer midi***, en référence à la position des aiguilles d’une horloge marquant cette heure du jour : être en érection.
- **Le sud**, la direction où se trouve le soleil en ce temps de la journée, duquel découle

  - Les régions du sud d’un pays *(le Midi de l’Italie)*

    - Plus précisément encore, les régions du sud de la France *(prendre ses vacances dans le Midi)*
- Le milieu d’un évènement temporel marqué d’un début et d’une fin, spécialement

  - Le midi de la vie, l’âge du plein épanouissement physique et intellectuel, métonymie dont l’origine pourrait remonter au sphinx qui posa son énigme *(Quel être, pourvu d’une seule voix, a d’abord quatre jambes le matin, puis deux jambes le midi, et trois jambes le soir ?)*, de laquelle découle...

    - ...une certaine idée d’apogée, symboliquement proche de ce sommet qu’atteint le soleil au milieu du jour avant d’entreprendre sa descente.

**Meridis**, midi en latin, a aussi quelques séquences de nouvelles significations :

- **L’heure méridienne** : midi, d’où

  - **La méridienne** : la sieste que l’on fait vers le milieu du jour, puis...

    - **Une méridienne** : un canapé sur lequel on se repose
- **Méridional** *adj* : du sud, de la position du soleil à midi

  - **Méridional, e** n : une personne du sud de la France
- **Méridien** :

  - *En astronomie, géographie* : chacun des grands cercles de la Terre, perpendiculaires à l’équateur et passant par ses pôles, ainsi nommé parce que le soleil intercepte le méridien local au milieu de sa course quotidienne. Viendra ensuite, s’éloignant de plus en plus du concept de la moitié du jour...

    - *En mathématiques, plus généralement* : intersection d’une surface de révolution et d’un plan par l’axe la générant.

Pourquoi *midi* aurait-il autant de séquences de nouvelles significations par métonymie ? L’expliquer sans davantage de réflexion et d’étude serait pure conjecture. Une première hypothèse pourrait être que midi est d’une grande importance symbolique dans la vie des sociétés humaines, et ce probablement depuis bien avant l’écriture, et qu’en conséquence il semblerait normal qu’on en discutât davantage et qu’on l’introduisît dans nombre de comparaisons, figures de style et métonymies. Mais il faut encore tester face à la réalité.

---

Il est intéressant de comparer les différents mots proposés jusqu’à présent :

- Bureau
- Calcul
- Mariage
- Midi
- Plume

Parmi ceux-ci :

- Deux cas émanant d’un objet naturel commun (plume, calcul), un autre inspiré par l’étude de l’alternance du jour et de la nuit, et donc du soleil, élément naturel unique et inaccessible, certes, mais néanmoins d’une extrême importance (midi). On pourra penser que cela leur donne une longueur d’avance sur d’autres termes, qui durent attendre de s’incarner dans l’humanité avant de devenir productif en métonymies successives. En creusant un peu, on pourrait penser à d’autres termes d’entités naturelles ayant généré quelques autres termes par métonymie ou par métaphore. Par exemple, **branche**, de l’arbre d’abord, puis de l’arbre généalogique, puis d’une discipline quelconque du savoir. **Herbe**, qui pourra désigner plus spécifiquement celles utilisées en cuisine, ou la marijuana, ou le printemps *(aux herbes)*, de ce dernier l’enfance, ou le début d’un apprentissage. **Verge**, baguette initialement, puis celle dont on corrige quelqu’un, puis la longueur de celle-ci. Aussi l’organe reproducteur du mâle chez l’humain et les mammifères en général. Un matériau commun apparu il y a longtemps dans les cultures humaines pourrait à la rigueur être assimilé à un matériau naturel, car ayant similairement un long historique linguistique. Nous avons par exemple le **cuivre**, dont l’étymologie nous indique que l’appelation vient par métonymie de l’île de Chypre, du fait que le cuivre était *du bronze de Chypre*. Les cuivres désignent aujourd’hui les chaudrons et casseroles d’une cuisine, ainsi que les instruments de musique habituellement fait de laiton. De ce dernier, on passe aussi à la section de tels instruments dans un orchestre, ou au timbre particulier de ce genre d’instrument. On désigna aussi par *cuivre* une pièce de monnaie faite de cuivre, puis tout type de monnaie.
- Deux qui sont plus ou moins des institutions, légale pour le mariage, économique ou politique pour le bureau. Peut-être le respect qu’impose ce genre d’institution aide à renommer ce qui les entoure ou entoure leur célébration, comme un prénom pourrait devenir populaire d’après une personnalité influente et respectée (Félix serait un exemple de ces dernières décennies au Québec). En suivant ce filon, on pourrait penser à **église**, le bâtiment spécifique, le lieu général de culte *(aller à l’église ne présuppose pas un bâtiment particulier)*, l’ensemble du monde ecclésiastique et la religion elle-même dans son ensemble. Ou alors à **justice**, qui est une institution tout autant que le principe morale qu’elle défend ou prétend défendre, ainsi que le résultat de ses jugements *(que justice me soit faite)* et l’application de ceux-ci *(justice fut rendue)*.
- Deux qui relèvent d’un art qui fut longtemps réservé à une élite (calcul, plume), et un autre indirectement (bureau). Est-ce par la qualité rare de leur maîtrise qu’ils furent productifs en métonymies, ou par la valeur attachée à leur production ? Ou est-ce que l’art lui-même, par ses facettes toujours changeantes et ses visions constamment nouvelles et frappantes, ne fournirait-il pas davantage de possibilités de métonymies ? Observons le théâtre, un art officiellement méprisé pendant longtemps en France *(Molière ne put recevoir de sépulture chrétienne)*. Serait-il lui aussi, en dépit de sa valeur très peu élitiste, susceptible de nous fournir des exemples de métonymies successives ? Premier constat, **théâtre** lui-même est à la fois l’art, le lieu de représentation, le bâtiment où a lieu ce genre de représentation et le style d’écriture destiné à être ainsi représenté. On pourra ensuite penser à la **scène**. De celle du théâtre à celle de la vie à celle d’un rassemblement ou d’une manifestation quelconque, puis à celle d’un crime ou d’un désastre humain ou même naturel, il y a toute une série de métonymies. Il semblerait que l’art pourrait être source de ce genre de chaîne de signifiés métonymiques successifs.

En dépit de tout ceci, de ces quelques pistes nous révélant plusieurs chaînes sans devoir fournir un effort trop poussé, je ne trouve pas de trait qui soit commun aux cinq mots initiaux. Ça laisse entrevoir que la métonymie pourrait bien fleurir un peu partout. Est-ce aussi la preuve qu’elle fait naturellement partie de l’esprit humain ? Je ne serais pas loin de le croire.

Je terminerai en citant Henri Suhamy, in *Les figures de style*, collection *Que sais-je ?* au Presses Universitaires de France, qui introduit ainsi son affirmation que la métonymie prolifère lorsque survient une spécialisation, pour laquelle de nombreux concepts devront être créés, le rapprochement métonymique étant une méthode simple et naturelle d’exprimer un grand nombre de ces nouveaux concepts :

> Les comportements langagiers sont mus par des mécanismes imitatifs, et sans aller jusqu’à imaginer une personnification de la langue et de son génie, on peut affirmer qu’elle agit souvent comme un locuteur collectif animé d’intentions stylistiques. D’autre part, l’exemple typiquement français du mot *vin* scintillant de mille reflets métonymiques révèle l’aspect ethnologique de la question : on parle à des initiés en leur fournissant sur l’objet du discours des précisions très fines qui remplacent le terme générique.

Comment: Merci ! Je salue votre effort. Et tenter de regrouper les exemples est particulièrement difficile ! Les institutions je ne sais pas si c'est tant le respect que l'importance ou le fait qu'il y ait davantage de complexité ; ou c'est l'ouverture d'un processus privé vers quelque chose de plus public ou officiel. Peut-être que le fonctionnement de la métonymie a quelque chose qui dépasse le cadre de la langue à proprement parler. Vos réflexions sont bien intéressantes, merci encore !

Comment: La complexité et l’abondance! Vous avez probablement mis le doigt sur ce qui pourrait unir la littérature — et les écrits d’une manière plus générale (plume) —, les mathématiques (calcul), les institutions (mariage, bureau, église, justice), et les arts plus communs (théâtre, peinture, cinéma) en opposition à ceux plus rares (sculpture) qui ne présentent guère ce fourmillement de données disparates au grand public. Reste le midi, qui n'est que commun, et dont la véritable complexité me semble davantage comprise et naturellement entrevue par les astrophysiciens que par le reste d'entre nous.

Answer (score 1):

Il semble y avoir une succession assez solide en ce qui concerne les sens qu'a acquis le mot « plume » et il est possible que quelques autres sens puissent être glissés dans la liste, comme par exemple la plume en tant que « polémique ».

1. appendice sur les ailes de l'oiseau
2. instrument pour écrire
3. art de former les lettres (avoir une belle plume)
4. moyen d'expression (la plume cèdera au sabre)
5. manière d'écrire (sous la plume de Debray)
6. profession (homme de plume, la plume a ses exigences)
7. écrivain (quelques plumes vénales)

Il existe une succession certaine dans le sens de l'aspect  pragmatique diminuant; du point de vue chronologie il se peut que la successivité soit rompue pour l'un des éléments à partir du quatrième.

Answer (score 1):

La séquence exacte de leurs apparition dans la langue demeure à établir, mais il y a sans conteste un grand jeu de poupées russes dans la notion de **mariage**, qui représente indifféremment :

- l’union permanente de deux personnes
- la cérémonie au cours de laquelle est établie l’union
- le cortège accompagnant le couple avant et après la cérémonie *(un bruyant mariage défilant dans la ville)*
- l’ensemble des festivités accompagnant ce jour *(les noces)*
- l’état d’union s’ensuivant *(préférer le mariage à la soutane<sup>1</sup>)*
- l’institution donnant un statut légal à une telle union

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>La soutane elle-même, décrivant l’état éclésiastique, est une acception arrivée par métonymie du vêtement typique de l’éclésiastique.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Se trouve ci-dessous un résumé très compréhensif de l'usage métonymique du mot « lit »,  que l'on peut consulter dans le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?14;s=584939145;r=1;nat=;sol=3;) en son entièreté, mais il n'y faut pas chercher une relation ininterrompue de passage de signifié en signifié. Je n'avance pas du tout ce mot comme  candidat au titre du mot dont l'évolution lexicale a amassé le plus grand nombre de concepts par métonymie mais comme un exemple de mot déjà remarquable par sa productivité sur le plan de son rendement métonymique. Je n'ai malheureusement pas le loisir de  pouvoir m'intéresser aux deux questions qui restent, telles qu'appliquées à ce mot, comme elles semblent demander un très important effort d'étude, en particulier pour le quasi non initié que je suis.

Lit :

1. coucher (le lit et la table)
2. alitement (garder le lit)
3. chez-soi (s'en retourner à son lit)
4. place dans un hôpital (il n'y a pas assez de lits dans cet hôpital)
5. mariage (issue d'un second lit)
6. acte sexuel (peu stimulant au lit)
7. activité sexuelle (pour le lit il n'était que peu enclin)
8. l'évidement incurvé du terrain dans lequel coule l'eau d'un cours d'eau
9. l'évidement incurvé des pentes d'une montagne dans lequel est logé un glacier
10. trajet habituel d'un vent (le lit de l'alizée)
11. direction d'où souffle le vent
12. couche d'un matériau (lit de pétales de roses)
13. assise (construction) (une assise de mortier, une assise de gravier,…)
14. (culinaire) garniture (rôti sur un lit de haricots)
15. champ (sens fig.)

Comment: Merci ! La présentation du mot est intéressante mais vous ne répondez pas à la question, soit celle des métonymies **successives**, et j'ai pris la peine de souligner ce terme et de préciser entre parenthèses ce que je recherche.